# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ReactComponent') when importing React component into my client-side component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, tsx

I have a component as client-side in order to use state called `DesktopNftView`. In it I want to display a grid of `nftCard`s. The `nftCard` is a composite component. For some reason one of the subcomponents called `ImageCol` is undefined when rendering, giving me an unhandled runtime error.

[image: Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ImageCol')]

I also get the message: `Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.`

`DesktopNftView`:

```
"use client";

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Container, Grid, NftCard, Select } from "ui";
import { SortOption, OptionsList, sortNftsBy } from "../../lib/utils/assetSorting";
import NFT from "../../assets/mock/collections/data/NFTProps";

const DesktopNftView = ({ tabComponent, nfts, }: {tabComponent: React.ReactNode, nfts: NFT[] }) => {
  const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState<SortOption>("")

  const sortedNfts = sortNftsBy(nfts, sortBy)

  const nftComponents = sortedNfts.map((nft: NFT) => (
    <NftCard
      boughtFor={String(nft.pricing.boughtFor)}
      className={"m-auto h-full"}
      collection={nft.collection}
      curated={nft.curated}
      currencySymbol={nft.pricing.currencySymbol}
      forSale={nft.pricing.forSale}
      key={nft.id}
      name={nft.name}
      price={String(nft.pricing.price)}
      rarityRank={{
        maxRank: String(nft.rarity.maxRank),
        rarityScore: String(nft.rarity.rarityScore),
        topPlacement: String(nft.rarity.topPlacement),
      }}
      src={nft.attributes.imageSrc}
      type={"collection"}
    />
  ));

  return (
    <>
      <Grid className="justify-between" columns={2} flex>
        {tabComponent}
        <Select id="assetSort" onChange={val => setSortBy(val as SortOption)} optionsList={OptionsList.slice() as string[]} placeholder="Sort By" type="assetSorting" width="80"/>
      </Grid>
      <Container bgColor="white" className="p-2 tablet:p-12" rounded>
        <Grid className={`p-auto`} columns={4} gap={6} mobileColumns={2} mobileGap={2}>
          {nftComponents}
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </>
  )
}
export default DesktopNftView
```

`NftCard`:

```
import React, {FC} from "react";
import {Container, Typography, Grid, ImageCol, IconButton, Icon, Tooltip} from "../..";
import {cls} from "../../utils";
import {ModalLocal} from "../../atoms/modalLocal/modalLocal";

interface Props {
  ...
}

export const NftCard: FC<Props> = ({
  className,
  src,
  width,
  bestOffer,
  boughtFor,
  favourited,
  unfavourite,
}) => {
  const profit = bestOffer && boughtFor && (parseFloat(bestOffer) - parseFloat(boughtFor)) / parseFloat(boughtFor) * 100

  return (
    <Container
      className={cls([
        className,
        "relative hover:shadow-card group",
        "box-border bg-eerie",
        "hover:shadow-card hover:bg-eerieLight cursor-pointer",
        width ? `w-${width}` : "max-w-nftCardMobile tablet:max-w-nftCard w-full",
      ])}
      gap={0}
      rounded
      width={"full"}
    >
      <div className={"relative h-nftCardMobile tablet:h-nftCard box-border mx-1 mt-1 mb-3 overflow-hidden rounded"}>
        <ImageCol className="relative group-hover:scale-125  ease-in-out transition-all max-h-full max-w-full"
          imageSrc={src} type={"nftCard"}
        />
        <Grid
          className="p-2 box-border h-full w-full absolute top-0 z-10"
          columns={2}
          flex
          justifyBetween
          mobileColumns={2}
        >
          <IconButton
            className={!favourited ? "hidden tablet:flex transition-opacity duration-200 opacity-full group-hover:opacity-none" : ""}
            icon={favourited ? "star" : "starOpen"}
            onClick={unfavourite}
            size={"small"}
            type={"secondaryTransparent"}
          />
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

`ImageCol`:

```
import React from "react";

interface ImageColProps {
  className?: string;
  children?: any;
  type?:
    | "collectionCardHeader"
    | "collectionCardSubItem"
    | "avatar"
    | "avatarSmall"
    | "blur"
    | "informationCardImage"
    | "nftCard"
    | "logo";

  imageSrc?: string;
}

export const ImageCol = ({
  type,
  className,
  imageSrc = "/images/nfts/ape3.png",
    children,
}: ImageColProps) => {
  return (
    <img
      alt={"2"}
      className={[
        className && `${className}`,
        type ? `h-${type} max-h-${type} ` : "w-full h-full",
        type === "avatar" || type === "avatarSmall"
          ? " aspect-square rounded-full  "
          : type === "collectionCardSubItem"
          ? "w-full rounded-xs"
          : type === "collectionCardHeader"
          ? "w-full rounded"
          : type === "informationCardImage"
          ? "w-full rounded"
          : type === "nftCard"
          ? "w-full rounded"
          : type === "logo"
          ? "w-auto object-contain"
          : "w-full",

        "object-cover ",
      ].join(" ")}
      src={imageSrc}
    >
        {children}
    </img>
  );
};
```

Switching the `DesktopNftView` renders without errors, but then I cannot make use of state, which is the point of the component. I also tried switching to default exports where possible, but that does not seem to help either.